# SELECT * INTO -> Excel worksheet using SQL Server 2008

Tags: sql-server, excel, select

I want to select from a SQL Server table directly into an empty Excel spreadsheet.

I can select FROM a spreadsheet into another SQL Server table (see example below).

I can select directly from ACCESS to an empty spreadsheet (see example below).

But I cannot find a way select from SQL Server directly into an empty spreadsheet.

(I manipulate a ton of legacy data by importing spreadsheets, manipulating the data several times, then I need to export it for consumption by other programs that require csv files.  Right now I have to create an intermediate step of pulling it into ACCESS to get it back out to Excel. I leverage the `SELECT * INTO` to format the tables because I format the source table as I work on the data.)

Thanks for the help.

I can `SELECT * INTO` a SQL Server table from Excel via the following code:

```
string query = "SELECT * INTO " + tableName + " " +
               "FROM OPENROWSET('Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0'," +
               "'Excel 12.0;Database=" + EXCELfilpath + ";IMEX=1'," +
               "'SELECT * FROM ["+sheetName+"$]')";
```

Also I can select from ACCESS table directly into Excel

```
 //Select the ACCESS Table INTO an Excel Spreadsheet
            try
            {
                //SELECT INTO command                
                string cnStr = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" + AccfilePath +
                   ";Persist Security Info=False";

                ConnOpen(cnStr);

                using (connectionToDatabase)
                {
                    //Give the Export Table (destination) a Name
                    //baseTblName = dt.TableName;

                    //Generate the SQL string to SELECT * INTO the NEW table in destination
                    string selectcmd = "SELECT * INTO [Excel 12.0;Database="+ExfilePath+"]." + tblName + " FROM " + tblName;


                    using (OleDbCommand createCmd = new OleDbCommand(selectcmd, connectionToDatabase))
                    {
                        createCmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                    }

                    ConnClose();
                }
            }
```

Answer (score 1):

I can't test it because of 64-bit, since OLE in general is working at your machine, this should work to

```
INSERT INTO OPENROWSET('Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0', 
'Excel 12.0;Database=C:\temp\Mappe1.xlsx;', 
'SELECT * FROM [Tabelle1$]') 
SELECT *  FROM ADDR
```

Comment: I get this error :Column name or number of supplied values does not match table definition.

Comment: I think this goes back to the SELECT * INTO versus INSERT INTO.  INSERT expects an existing table.

Comment: Sorry, as I told you, I can not test anymore, my environment an home is complete 64-bit (Office 32-Bit). I can try tomorrow in the office. Perhaps meanwhile this will help?

http://blog.waynesheffield.com/wayne/code-library/ad-hoc-querying/#codesyntax_5

Comment: Thanks, I took a look at the link.  The file has to preexist with the correct column names for those examples.  I can wait to see what you come up with tomorrow at the office.  (I have been trying to solve this for about 3 months so another day won't hurt.)  Thanks for the help.